# Header Cell of UITableView in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode13, uitableviewsectionheader

I am using a UITableView with the header. For the header I use **viewForHeaderInSection**. I have a label and a button in my header cell. I also have an array to give my headerViewCell's label a name. My array is

```
let cellArray = ["Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Girraffe", "Zebra"]
```

I am adding an **@objc** function for the headerViewCell's button and using the tag for the button.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderTableViewCell") as! HeaderTableViewCell

    headerView.cellLabel.text = self.cellArray[section]
    headerView.cellButton.tag = section
    headerView.cellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandRow(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return headerView
}
```

My question is I want to change the **cellLabel** in the **@objc func** of the selected Cell. Let suppose I tap on 1st cell, I want to change the 1st cell **Label Name** but don't know how to do it.

This was easy if we are using the rows instead of headers as there is **cellForRowAt** for the rows. But I am not able to access that selected header cell.

Does anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on my own. This is what I am doing in the **@objc func**:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: sender.section) as? HeaderTableViewCell

cell.cellLabel.text = "monkey"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `cellArray` as `var`

```
var cellArray = ["Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Girraffe", "Zebra"]
```

Then inside `@objc` function change the model

```
cellArray[tag] = //// new content
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I also have an image in my header cell. The image is saved in my assets. What to do if I have to change image of the selected cell?

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func expandRow(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    cellArray[sender.tag] = "new value"
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I also have an image in my header cell. The image is saved in my assets. What to do if I have to change image of the selected cell?